# Animate textarea height makes text shake?

Tags: jquery

I have animated a text area to increase in height and rows on a button click. However during the animation the text area's text shakes up and down and once the animation finishes it has moved up a bit. How can I stop this?

Here is my code:

Thanks :)

```
function morespace(){
var thetxt = document.getElementById('more').value;
var box = document.forms["myForm"]["comment"];
if(box.rows == 3)
{
    $("#emailme").fadeOut(200);
    $('#comment').animate({'height': '+=235'},400,"swing");
    box.rows = 17;
    document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "less space?";
}
else
{
    $('#comment').animate({'height': '-=235'},400,"swing");
    $("#emailme").fadeIn(800);
    box.rows = 3;
    document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "more space?";
}}
```

`<a href="javascript:morespace();" id="more">more space?</a>`

UPDATE: you ask for jsfiddle I provide jsfiddle ^_^ http://jsfiddle.net/qs3VA/4/

Comment: Maybe a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example would be nice to go with this question ;-)

Comment: Second on the jsFiddle request

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing. JSFiddle!

Comment: there you go :) jsfiddle link :) http://jsfiddle.net/qs3VA/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that decimal heights cause the flicker. I changed it to use a linear growth, with a time that is equal to the amount of pixels to change, or a multiple thereof (So that the height is always an integer).

```
function morespace()
{
    var thetxt = document.getElementById('more').value;
    var box = document.forms["myForm"]["comment"];
    if(box.rows == 3)
    {
        $("#emailme").fadeOut(200);
        $('#comment').animate({'height': '+=235'},235,"linear");
        box.rows = 17;
        document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "less space?";
    }
    else
    {
        $('#comment').animate({'height': '-=235'},470,"linear");
        $("#emailme").fadeIn(800);
        box.rows = 3;
        document.getElementById('more').innerHTML = "more space?";
    }
}​
```

We are forcing jQuery to never assign a height of "x.12343654234"

Hopefully this is acceptable for your requirements.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qs3VA/15/

Comment: Well, its less noticeable, but still there... hmmm.